# Private VLANs implementation

Tags: cisco-catalyst, private-vlan

So, I have campus LAN, implemented as many VLANs with InterVLAN routing, that spreads on tens of L2 switches and one L3 switch. Now, I have request that hosts on one VLAN don't see each other. But, those hosts, on that VLAN, are spread on many different switches.

So, my questions are:

1. Do I have to configure/define all of the existing VLANs as Primary and  Secondary types, or only the one I need to isolate?
2. What of the existing VLANs would be primary VLAN? Or should I create new VLAN and define it as Primary?
3. Trunk ports between the switches will be Promiscuous ports?

Comment: You may need to provide your switch models to get good answers.

Comment: These are all Cisco catalyst switches with IOS.

Comment: You'd have a much easier time just implementing VACLs (VLAN ACLs or VLAN access-maps).  You can check out an example here: https://www.networkstraining.com/vlan-access-map-example-configuration/

Comment: A VACL allows you to filter layer 2 traffic just like you would with a router ACL.

Comment: My default answer to such requests is "it doesn't work like that." If you want hosts to not "see each other", then don't put them in the same network. (with *very* few exceptions: eg. AP isolation for guest wifi)